# I want to know the exact formula to calculate metabolic age

Tags: weight-loss, metabolism

I want to know the exact formula to calculate metabolic age. How do i get the average bmr of people in the chronological age group? Is here any link I could get regarding the calculation?
Explanation in detail would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: How is this related to fitness?

Comment: I think "How do i get the average bmr of people in the chronological age group?" is off-topic for this stackexchange. Perhaps at biology.stackexchange you could get a better answer.

Comment: Also, there is no formula to calculate "average BMR in a chronological age group". This is a statistical calculation achieved through sampling/polling. It is not a formulaic calculation thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the page at [Wikipedia, at the section BMR estimation formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basal_metabolic_rate#BMR_estimation_formulas)

There are several formulas there, I'll not copy/paste everything, better to look there for more explanations.

**The Original Harris-Benedict Equation [1919]**

for men: [image]

for women: [image]

where P is total heat production at complete rest, m is the weight, h is the height, and a is the age, and with the difference in BMR for men and women being mainly due to differences in body weight.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgCvv.png) For example, a 55 year old woman weighing 130 lb (59 kg) and 5 feet 6 inches (168 cm) tall would have a BMR of 1272 kcal per day or 53 kcal/h (61.3 watts).
In 1984, the original Harris-Benedict equations were revised[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBggO.png) using new data. In comparisons with actual expenditure, the revised equations were found to be more accurate.[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZhZo.png)

**The Revised Harris-Benedict Equation [1984]**

for men: [image]

for women: [image]

**The Mifflin St Jeor Equation [1990]**

[image] where s is +5 for males and −161 for females.

**The Katch-McArdle Formula (BMR)**

[image] where LBM is the lean body mass in kg

**The Cunningham Formula (RMR)**

[image] where LBM is the lean body mass in kg

Comment: thanks again, but i have read all those, these are calculations for BMR, but metabolic age is calculated by comparing your Basal Metabolic Rate to the Basal Metabolic Rate average of your chronological age group. So I want to know how to find Basal Metabolic Rate average of a chronological age group.
Or is there any particular formula available, so I could calculate it manually.

Comment: How do you divide a subject in chronological age groups?